# java - map to store key and multiple type of values

Tags: java

Basically I'd like something like this: `Hashmap<String, String/int>` a python equivalent to dictionary in java so be able to store key and value pair, only in my case I need to store the value which can be an int or a string. E.g. of value I'd like to store would be:

```
{"one":1,
"two":"two"}
```

So, it's not storing multiple values in one key, just multiple type of value with one type of key. One solution would be to use `Hashmap<String, Object>` and check the `Object` instance at runtime, but that really feels tricky and you'd have to check all the values. Is there a more proper way?

Comment: Not really! As a rule of thumb, and unless really important, you should use members of one type as a value in a `Collection`. The closest you can do is to use `<String, String>` but that comes with its own challenges:  How do you know if "1" is `String` or `Integer`?

Comment: Why can't the second pair just be a String... 1 can be converted to a String.

Comment: @Prashant , good point, but, I insert these values to a database so I just knew it could either be a textual data or a digit, but this is another challenge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no another way to do it.
"Everything" in Java extends from Object.

You can create a helper class to handle the checking type or even extend HashMap and create your own getValue method, using generics, like following:

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    @Nullable
    public <V> V getValue(@Nullable String key) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (V) super.get(key);
    }
}
```

And using like this:

```
    MyHashMap map = new MyHashMap();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", "two");

    Integer one = map.getValue("one");
    String two = map.getValue("two");
```

Or even:

```
 public void printNumber(Integer number){
    // ...
 }

printNumber(map.<Integer>getValue("one"));
```

Comment: the problem with this is, you can't use key/value pair in a loop since you have to pass in `<dataType>` generic parameter. I was basically thinking of using that so as to loop through the schema and value pair otherwise I'd have to either sync two arrays or define the schema everytime

Comment: You can do it like this:  

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
               map.getValue(entry.getKey());
 }

Once HashMap.get(key)  is O(1).